# CK editor- multiple styles to elements

Tags: ckeditor, styles

I wonder if any of you are CK editor experts? The way that CK editor is set up, when I add multiple styles to a selection of text, it will wrap the text in span tags with style attributes- but it will use a new tag for each style- which often results in the styles being lost.

For example, if I wanted to apply the following styles to a selection of text- bold, font-size:22px and color:red - CK editor would output the following HTML:

```
<span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0);"><span style="font-size: 22px;"><strong>Testing</strong></span></span>
```

Which doesn't apply the styles properly. Does anyone know how to set it up to output like:

```
<span style="color:rgb(255,0,0);font-size: 22px;font-weight:bold">Testing</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems stupid that CK editor does this by default. I've been reading the documentation for the last few hours but can't find much that helps me. This is almost there- http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7813 but I can't find the config file where this is?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem ? facing the same issue here...

Thank you,

Mat